# Broken autobinding in arrow function for referenced node modules when using react-native with react-relay

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs, arrow-functions, relay

I'm using react-native and react-relay, therefore I've the following .babelrc file:

```
{
  "sourceMaps": "both",
  "presets": [
    "./plugins/babelRelayPlugin",
    "react-native"
  ],
  "passPerPreset": true
}
```

Adding a dependency which uses arrow functions in their components as the MKIconToggle from react-native-material-kit (https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit) doesn't get transpiled correctly and the this reference is lost/wrong.

The original code which ultimately causes the error looks like the following:

```
_onLayout = (evt) => {
    this._onLayoutChange(evt.nativeEvent.layout);

    if (this.props.onLayout) {
      this.props.onLayout(evt);
    }
  };
```

The affected code fragment in the error case:

```
d(55, function(global, require, module, exports) {var _this = this,
    _jsxFileName = '.../node_modules/react-native-material-kit/lib/mdl/Ripple.js';
var Ripple = function (_Component) {
  babelHelpers.inherits(Ripple, _Component);

  function Ripple(props) {
    babelHelpers.classCallCheck(this, Ripple);

    var _this2 = babelHelpers.possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(Ripple).call(this, props));

    _this2._onLayout = function (evt) {
      _this._onLayoutChange(evt.nativeEvent.layout);

      if (_this.props.onLayout) {
        _this.props.onLayout(evt);
      }
    };
```

The _this reference equals window, due to the usage of _this the _this2 is created and used but _this is still used in the arrow functions(_onLayout)

When I delete the babelrc file and the default runs I get the following transpiled JS and it works:

```
__d(921, function(global, require, module, exports) {var jsxFileName='...../node_modules/react-native-material-kit/lib/mdl/Ripple.js';

Component=React.Component;var Animated=React.Animated;var View=React.View;var PropTypes=React.PropTypes;var Platform=React.Platform;var Ripple=function(_Component){
babelHelpers.inherits(Ripple,_Component);
function Ripple(props){babelHelpers.classCallCheck(this,Ripple);
var _this=babelHelpers.possibleConstructorReturn(this,Object.getPrototypeOf(Ripple).call(this, props));
_this._onLayout=function(evt){
_this._onLayoutChange(evt.nativeEvent.layout);

if(_this.props.onLayout){
_this.props.onLayout(evt);}};_this.
```

I'm not really certain what causes the issue, I can fix it by binding the function in the constructor but I'd rather not change code in dependencies directly.
I've already tried to add various presets to the babel conf: es2015, stage-0, babel-preset-react-native-stage-0 and some others all without luck.

Funny thing is this behaviour doesn't occur in all dependencies and also not in my own code, if I just write a single component with an arrow function in it and use the babelrc it still works.

I'm not able to 100% reproduce this behaviour, I've seen it with other dependencies as well but it seems to come and go, although once it occurs it doesn't usually go away anymore.

Answer (score 0):

babel-preset-react-native-stage-0 did it in the end.
Not sure what was left in the cache or somewhere else but after clearing it all with:

`watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npm start --reset-cache`

my project and all it's arrow functions work.