# This is no longer bound when using arrow functions after upgrading to React Native 26

Tags: react-native, babeljs, relayjs

In my project `this` is no longer bound when using arrow functions after upgrading to React Native 26.

If I don't use a `.babelrc` in the example below it works with arrow functions.  When a `.babelrc` is added arrow functions no longer work.

## .babelrc

`{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [
    {"plugins":["../schema/babelRelayPlugin"]},
    "react-native",
  ]
}`

I also tried:

`{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [
    {"plugins":["../schema/babelRelayPlugin"]},
    "react-native-stage-0",
  ]
}`

and

`{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [
    {"plugins":["../schema/babelRelayPlugin"]},
    "react-native",
    {"plugins":["transform-es2015-arrow-functions"]},
  ]
}`

---

### This errors

```
class NoArrow extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={x:0};
  }

  inc = ()=>{
    this.setState({x:this.state.x+1});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome} onPress={this.inc}>
          Welcome to React Native! {this.state.x}
        </Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

### [image]

### This works

```
class NoArrow extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={x:0};
    this.inc=this.inc.bind(this);
  }

  inc(){
    this.setState({x:this.state.x+1});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome} onPress={this.inc}>
          Welcome to React Native! {this.state.x}
        </Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When adding/removing `.babelrc` also run:

- watchman watch-del-all
- npm start --reset-cache
- I also edit the file (adding a comment) to make sure it recompiles.

---

Side note: funny thing is this works even with the `.babelrc`

```
class NoArrow extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={x:0};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome} onPress={()=> this.setState({x:this.state.x+1})}>
          Welcome to React Native! {this.state.x}
        </Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

---

---

---

### Update 1

Inside $TMPDIR delete the cached file; it has a hashed name like `11acb28f1c8d3c6313ca5f8ccba3c158`

Using `react-native-stage-0` might have fixed the arrow function issue, but now Relay.QL are no longer compiled correctly.

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [
    {"plugins":["../schema/babelRelayPlugin"]},
    "react-native-stage-0"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example snippet of code we could look at? Are you able to reproduce the issue on https://babeljs.io/repl/ for example?

Comment: An example has been added. I'm pretty sure something in my package.json or .babelrc is causing the issue.

Comment: adding the .babelrc is definitely this issue, not sure what the solution is though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem, but I'm pretty sure it predated RN 0.24. What version of babel-core/babel-cli do you have? I had been hopeful that [T7191](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T7191) would fixed the problem, but it did not.

What I ended up doing was using [babel-relay-plugin-loader](https://github.com/BerndWessels/babel-relay-plugin-loader). I no longer use passPerPreset anymore, and it has been working reliably, though I don't completely understand how.

Here is what my .babelrc looks like now:

```
{
"presets": [
    "react-native"
],
"plugins": [
    "babel-relay-plugin-loader"
],
"env": {
    "web": {
        "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
        "plugins": ["babel-relay-plugin-loader"]
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is really related to 26, I had the same issue with 25.
See my post here:
[Broken autobinding in arrow function for referenced node modules when using react-native with react-relay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324044/broken-autobinding-in-arrow-function-for-referenced-node-modules-when-using-reac)

For me the issue isn't persistent and after tinkering with it for a while it's gone for good. Seemingly the react-native-stage-0 did it for me.
When clearing the cache the only thing you didn't do is clear the $TMPDIR like this: `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*`

I've tried to reproduce my issue with a sample project but wasn't able to, I'd try to rm -rf the node_modules as well, just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks!  I upgraded to RN26 from RN24, so it was probably introduced in RN25. Adding react-native-stage-0 fixed arrow functions but from relay.  Were you able to get arrow functions and relay working together? Can you post your entire .babrc.

Comment: Yes, it works: `{
  "sourceMaps": "inline",
  "presets": [
    "./plugins/babelRelayPlugin",
    "react-native-stage-0"
  ],
  "passPerPreset": true
}
` and here is the babelRelayPlugin: `const getBabelRelayPlugin = require('babel-relay-plugin')
const schema = require('../../data/schema.json')

module.exports = { plugins: [getBabelRelayPlugin(schema.data, { abortOnError: true })] };
`